# remove stopword in each tokenized row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, stop-words

I'm trying to remove stopwords from each row of my dataframe and put it into a new dataframe column S.

I've tried below code but it doesn't seem to work...

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = stopwords.words('english')

df['S'] = df.apply(lambda row: (word for word in row['remarks_tokenized'] if word.lower() not in stopwords), axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this for a different corpus and it works.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords  
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize  
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))  

def remove_stopwords(sentence):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(sentence)  
    clean_tokens = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]  
    
    return clean_tokens
    
df['S'] = df['remarks'].apply(remove_stopwords)
```

output:

```
0     [microsoft, word, arma2011paper353, prediction...
1     [2504, 0478, matava, qxd, gulf, mexico, mature...
2     [lithospheric, structure, texas, gulf, mexico,...
4     [int, see, discussions, stats, author, profile...
5     [bltn9556, authors, thomas, r, taylor, shell, ...
7     [high, resolution, reservoir, characterization...
8     [untitled, journal, sedimentary, research, v, ...
9     [doi, j, epsl, www, elsevier, com, locate, eps...
10    [authors, dale, e, bird, department, geoscienc...
11    [spe, ms, spe, ms, taking, co2, enhanced, oil,...
```

Comment: I also enjoy using texthero to pre-process the corpus. highly recommend it in case you have not tried it before